# How to add space between two variables?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a problem to add space between the `firstName` and `lastName` fields. I'm trying to display the first name and last name on one line, but there is no space between them. How can I add a space? These fields are from my database on SQL Server. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tutor
        {
            color: #000000;
            font-family: "Arial";
            font-size: large;
        }        
        .data
        {
            font-family: "Arial";
            font-size: large;
        }        
        .heading
        {
            font-family: "Arial";
            font-size: xx-large;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #ABCDEF;
        } 

    <title>Tutor Contact List</title>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="heading">Tutor Contact List</div><br/>
    <xsl:for-each select="list/tutorcontact">
        <div class="tutor">Tutor Name:  
            <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></div>
        <div class="data"><b>Phone:</b>  
            <xsl:value-of select="phone"/></div>
        <div class="data"><b>E-Mail:</b>  
            <xsl:value-of select="email"/></div><br />
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the XPATH concat function

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tutor
        {
            color: #000000;
            font-family: "Arial";
            font-size: large;
        }        
        .data
        {
            font-family: "Arial";
            font-size: large;
        }        
        .heading
        {
            font-family: "Arial";
            font-size: xx-large;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #ABCDEF;
        } 

    <title>Tutor Contact List</title>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="heading">Tutor Contact List</div><br/>
    <xsl:for-each select="list/tutorcontact">
        <div class="tutor">Tutor Name:  
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(firstname,' ',lastname)"/>
        </div>
        <div class="data"><b>Phone:</b>  
            <xsl:value-of select="phone"/></div>
        <div class="data"><b>E-Mail:</b>  
            <xsl:value-of select="email"/></div><br />
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="tutor">Tutor Name:  
    <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></div>
```

In an XSLT stylesheet text nodes that consist *only* of whitespace are ignored by default except

- inside `<xsl:text>` or
- inside an element that has `xml:space="preserve"`

So the newline and spaces between `Tutor Name:` and the `lastname` will be preserved (because while that text node contains whitespace, it doesn't contain *only* whitespace) but the ones between the two `value-of` elements will be ignored.  If you want to have white space in the output at a place where it would be ignored in the stylesheet then you need to make it explicit with

```
<div class="tutor">Tutor Name:  
    <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></div>
```

but personally I'd just use the approach [suggested by OJay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23461189/592139) and just use one `value-of` with `concat(lastname, ' ', firstname)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<div class="tutor">Tutor Name:  
        <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>&nbsp;
        <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></div>
```

Comment: I have error: "XML Parsing Error: undefined entity"

Comment: `&nbsp;` is a pre-defined entity in HTML but not in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Unicode non-breaking space : `&#160;` or `&#32;`